# expose cluster to outside on cloud

Tags: amazon-web-services, networking, amazon-ec2, devops, amazon-eks

I was thinking to expose each service through cluster IP and have them whitelist all of them

Comment: Usually you would use NAT gateway's IP for that. I'm not sure your cluster is using VPC with nat?

Comment: @marcin, thank you for getting back to me. is this safe?

Comment: Yes. NAT gateway only allows outgoing internet connections. No one will be able to access your services from the internet through NAT.

Comment: Thanks! This has solved the issue

Comment: Glat to hear that. I added the answer. If it is helpful, it's acceptance would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the comments.

The solution was to use NAT gateway IP for whitelisting. The IP is static and also does not allow incoming connections from internet. Only outgoing Internet connections are allowed through NAT gateway.